# Como pegar o valor de vários select em um mesmo change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basicamente, tenho um botão que adiciona dois campos ao ser clicado, um input number e um select:

```
<div class="geraInput">
    <div id="form-conjunto">
        <select class="input select mb-1" name="produto[]">
            <optgroup label="Selecione o produto">
               <?php
                    foreach ($dados as $produtos):
               ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $produtos['id']?>"><?php echo $produtos['nome_produto']?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <input type="number" name="qtd[]" min="0" class="input number" placeholder="Quantidade" required><br/><br/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Ao clicar no botão, adiciona uma nova div de inputs
    $('.addInput').click(function () {
        //Clona a div e salva na variável clone
        var clone = $('.form-conjunto').clone();
        //Gera a nova div
        $('.geraInput').append(clone);
    });
});
```

Eu tenho outro script que pega dinamicamente o valor do select para que o input number tenha um max de acordo com o produto seleciona, faço isso via ajax mas, o jQuery só está pegando o valor do primeiro select e replicando em todos os inputs.

```
 $('.select').change(function () {
        var max = $('.select').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'AjaxReq/baixa.php',
            data: {id: max},
            success:function (html) {
                $('select').parent().find('.number').attr('max', html);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Como você estava usando o seletor de classe para pegar o valor de max, ele pega sempre o primeiro da tela. Troca para pegar o valor do select que esta sendo alterado, usando o `$(this)`:

```
$('.select').change(function () {
    var max = $(this).val();
    ...
});
```

Comment: Funcionou, troquei os 2 seletores pelo this. Thanks